# Adding tags to (suggested) edits

Tags: feature-request, tagging, editing, suggested-edits

Can I user with sufficient reputation (1000) to create new tags add these tags to suggested edits? What about users with sufficient reputation (2000) to edit posts?

Comment: You are more than welcome to add relevant existing tags to any question you see, and to remove the not-so-appropriate ones. At this point our tagging system has matured quite a bit. I really recommend that you bring up suggestions for new tags in threads like [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19037/11619) before using them. Newish users often suggest tags that are not really needed or not well received, and those are later purged causing just more work. Not implying that your suggested new tag would be a bad one, but IMO it is better to discuss new tags in advance.

Comment: BTW, wait for users more involved in tagging to comment. Me carrying a diamond does not mean that I would be well informed with the problems in our tagging system. I just wanted to give you my impression of were we are as a site. If you peruse the posts in the meta-threads related to tagging you will quickly learn who those users are.

Comment: Since this is labelled a feature request, are you asking to modify the suggested edit? For 2k+, the options Edit and Reject and Edit are available, which allow to expand upon/replace a suggestion.

Comment: I labelled it a feature request, because I tried to suggest a new tag as part of my edit suggestion, and it appeared as though the suggestion didn't even make it to the reviewer. So I am suggesting that new tags be suggested at the same time as an edit is suggested or added at the same time as an edit is made. Unless this is already the case and I did something wrong. Or the phone app doesn't offer this feature.

Comment: Do you remember which post were you editing? Is it listed among [your suggested edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/266049/adam-hrankowski?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)? In short, can you give as some link showing where the problem happened?

Comment: It's here. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457459/266049 My edit was approved, but I don't know if my new tag suggestion was even seen. I know I can create tags to my own questions.

Comment: However, if I look at the [review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/492895) or [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1457459/revisions) I do not see any changes in tags. What tag were you trying to add?

Comment: You mention in your comment that you were not doing this from a browser. (I did not notice this detail before.) It seems that creating tags from the mobile apps is not possible at the moment. There is a feature request on meta.SE: [Allow creating new tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/). (The post is more than one year old. But if there were any changes about that, I think they would have been mentioned there or in the linked posts.) However, I would expect that you get some error message, as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063).